When we build docusaurus build, it creates a file as rumtime~main.[hash].js. The question is can we avoid ~ in the name?
I am using docusaurus library to build the documentation for my application. For details please refer https://docusaurus.io/
Eveyrthing works well,but when i build the site using the command
docusaurus build

It generate the site as expected and it works very well. However in the build folder it generates few files, among them there is one  file which is
runtime~main.c20a87de.js
The problem with this naming convention, when i try to deploy it to the server and browse the documentation. The search box is not functional and when i checked the why?
I see a browser error in console
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500.
This is because my server prohibits the name with tilt(~)
I tried multiple approaches to override but nothing seems working.
module.exports = function forceWebpackRuntimeConfig() {
  return {
    name: 'force-webpack-runtime-config',
    configureWebpack(config, isServer) {
      // Explicitly override runtimeChunk
      config.optimization.runtimeChunk = {
        name: () => `runtime.[contenthash]`, // Generates runtime.[contenthash].js
      };

      // Override output filenames
      config.output.filename = '[name].[contenthash].js';
      config.output.chunkFilename = '[name].[contenthash].chunk.js';

      return config;
    },
  };
};`

I am trying to find if we can avoid the name being generated without tilt.
If you need more infromatio, please do let me know 

Thank you
Bharat


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/YjvB5dx7.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/iV6pNWCj.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/Lhw2psVd.png


When we downvote something, at lest tell us what needs to be done...simply downvoting is discouraging and of no use

The issue was the way i was adding the section that will override the webpack settings was incorrect and also I neded to check the if (!isServer) condition
plugins: [
    function customWebpackPlugin() {
      return {
        name: 'custom-webpack-plugin',
        configureWebpack(config, isServer, utils) {
          // Apply this configuration only for client-side builds
          if (!isServer) {
            return {
              optimization: {
                runtimeChunk: {
                  name: () => `runtime.main`, // Custom runtime file name
                },
              },
              output: {
                ...config.output,
                filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js', // Custom path for main files
                chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js', // Custom path for chunk files
              },
            };
          }
          return {};
        },
      };
    },
  ],

Once I added the above code to docusaurus.config.ts now its not adding the tilt
Thank you
Bharat
